# Async mounted hook is not awaiting Feathers-Vuex useFind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, feathers-vuex

I'm having some trouble getting the array in `books.value` to log to the console. It continues to return no results even after awaiting the `useFind` function. I have confirmed results exist for the value I pass into the query. If I make a change to the code without refreshing my browser, the `console.log` will work. What am I doing wrong?

```
  import { useFind } from "feathers-vuex";

  async mounted() {
    const { Book } = this.$FeathersVuex.api;
    const pathBody = this.$route.path.split("/")[1];

    const bookParams = computed(() => {
      return {
        query: {
          referral_link: pathBody
        }
      };
    });

    const { items: books } = await useFind({
      model: Book,
      params: bookParams
    });

    console.log(books.value); // empty array
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `useFind` you need to use vue composable api instead of normal functions/options.

Here's how it should looks like instead:

```
export default {
  component: 'PageName',
  setup(_ , { root }) {
    const { Book } = root.$FeathersVuex.api;
    const pathBody = root.$route.path.split("/")[1];

    const bookParams = computed(() => {
      return {
        query: {
          referral_link: pathBody
        }
      };
    });

    const { items: books } = await useFind({
      model: Book,
      params: bookParams
    });

    return {
      books
    }
  }
}
```

Also the data on won't be there on `mounted` since it took time to actually fetch. You can add `isPending` besides the returned `items`. Then use it on your template with `v-if`.